# Interactive timeline charts for interval event [label; start : end] data?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am newbie to JS. I want to visualize the time interval data where each event is defined as follows:

```
[label; start time: end time]
```

**Label: string** And **Start/end time are in millisecond/microseconds**

I can visualize this data with Google Timeline visualization:

[image]

But I want add some other properties to this. Since my interval data will be in milliseconds.

- I want to have grid spaced lets say some x values.
- Labeled X - axis like 0----5----10----15
- **Zooming option**: Similar to what we have in Google AnnotatedTimeLine. Since a given row we may have thousands of events and we are interested to analyze the details within given time range [2200ms-2500ms].

[image]

how can we have zooming option in TimeLine like given in above image(AnnotatedTimeLine ).

In Short, I am seeking Google AnnotatedTimeLine like facilities in Google TimeLine package. How can I do that ?

Since our data is interval data (not a time-series data) we can't use AnnotatedTimeLine visualization.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4):

first, there aren't any [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#configuration-options) to control the x-axis labels
they are set dynamically when the chart is drawn, and change depending on the time range displayed

next, the *zooming option* found on an [annotation chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart) is available as a control for any chart

the [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) can be bound to a chart using a [Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#dashboard)

see following working snippet...

(adapted from another answer)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawDashboard,
  packages: ['controls']
});

function drawDashboard() {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard')
  );

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 3,
      ui: {
        minRangeSize: (60 * 60 * 1000),
        chartType: 'TimeLine',
        chartOptions: {
          width: 900,
          height: 70,
          chartArea: {
            width: '100%',
            height: '80%'
          },
          hAxis: {
            baselineColor: 'none'
          }
        },
        chartView: {
          columns: [3, 4]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'error', function (error) {
    console.log('error: ' + error.id + ' - ' + error.message);
    google.visualization.errors.removeError(error.id);
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Timeline',
    containerId: 'chart',
    options: {
      width: 985,
      height: 600,
      chartArea: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '80%'
      },
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      }
    },
    view: {
      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
  });

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Student' });
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Event Type' });
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
  data.addColumn({ type: 'datetime', id: 'Start' });
  data.addColumn({ type: 'datetime', id: 'End' });
  data.addRows([
    ['Student 571', 'Pretest', 'Student 571 began Biological Chemistry Learning Path Pretest', new Date(2015,08,10,18,52,02), new Date(2015,08,10,18,52,27)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Amino Acids videos', new Date(2015,08,10,18,52,27), new Date(2015,08,10,18,52,32)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Video: Bio102 water', new Date(2015,08,10,18,52,32), new Date(2015,08,10,18,52,33)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Amino Acids videos', new Date(2015,08,10,18,52,33), new Date(2015,08,10,18,52,40)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 viewed Elements of the Major Organic Compounds of Life', new Date(2015,08,10,18,52,40), new Date(2015,08,10,18,52,55)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 viewed Amino Acids videos', new Date(2015,08,10,18,52,55), new Date(2015,08,10,19,01,48)],
    ['Student 571', 'Supplemental Info', 'Student 571 viewed Carbohydrates Websites', new Date(2015,08,10,19,01,48), new Date(2015,08,10,19,01,49)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 viewed Lipids Textbooks', new Date(2015,08,10,19,01,49), new Date(2015,08,10,19,02,13)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 viewed Video: Bio102 Water', new Date(2015,08,10,19,02,13), new Date(2015,08,10,19,02,42)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Amino Acids videos', new Date(2015,08,10,19,02,42), new Date(2015,08,10,19,03,02)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Amino Acids videos', new Date(2015,08,10,19,03,02), new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,08)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Video: Bio102 Water', new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,08), new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,11)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 viewed Elements of the Major Organic Compounds of Life', new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,11), new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,18)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 viewed Biological Buffers Website 3 (animation)', new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,18), new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,42)],
    ['Student 571', 'Supplemental Info', 'Student 571 viewed Carbohydrates Websites', new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,42), new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,48)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 viewed Lipids Textbooks', new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,48), new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,53)],
    ['Student 571', 'Supplemental Info', 'Student 571 viewed Nucleic Acids Websites', new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,53), new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,54)],
    ['Student 571', 'Supplemental Info', 'Student 571 watched Video: The Properties of Water', new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,54), new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,55)],
    ['Student 571', 'Supplemental Info', 'Student 571 viewed Lipids Websites', new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,55), new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,57)],
    ['Student 571', 'Supplemental Info', 'Student 571 viewed Complex Carbohydrates Are Formed by Linkage of Monosaccharides - Biochemistry - NCBI Bookshelf', new Date(2015,08,10,19,16,57), new Date(2015,08,10,19,17,03)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Amino Acids Videos', new Date(2015,08,10,19,17,03), new Date(2015,08,10,19,18,27)],
    ['Student 571', 'Questions', 'Student 571 answered Cell-surface receptors question correctly', new Date(2015,08,10,19,18,27), new Date(2015,08,10,19,18,59)],
    ['Student 571', 'Questions', 'Student 571 answered Cell-surface receptors question incorrectly', new Date(2015,08,10,19,18,59), new Date(2015,08,10,19,19,21)],
    ['Student 571', 'Questions', 'Student 571 answered Cell-surface receptors question correctly', new Date(2015,08,10,19,19,21), new Date(2015,08,10,19,19,27)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Video: Bio102 Water', new Date(2015,08,10,19,19,27), new Date(2015,08,10,19,19,43)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Video: Bio102 Water', new Date(2015,08,10,19,19,43), new Date(2015,08,10,19,19,56)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Amino Acids Videos', new Date(2015,08,10,19,19,56), new Date(2015,08,10,19,19,57)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Video: Bio102 Water', new Date(2015,08,10,19,19,57), new Date(2015,08,10,19,20,33)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Amino Acids Videos', new Date(2015,08,10,19,20,33), new Date(2015,08,10,19,21,00)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Amino Acids Videos', new Date(2015,08,10,19,21,00), new Date(2015,08,10,19,21,02)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Video: Bio102 Water', new Date(2015,08,10,19,21,02), new Date(2015,08,10,19,21,50)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 watched Video: Bio102 Water', new Date(2015,08,10,19,21,50), new Date(2015,08,10,19,22,14)],
    ['Student 571', 'Questions', 'Student 571 answered Properties of Water question correctly', new Date(2015,08,10,19,22,14), new Date(2015,08,10,19,30,32)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 viewed Elements of the Major Organic Compounds of Life', new Date(2015,08,10,19,30,32), new Date(2015,08,10,20,21,16)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 viewed Biological Buffers Website 3 (animation)', new Date(2015,08,10,20,21,16), new Date(2015,08,10,20,22,01)],
    ['Student 571', 'Supplemental Info', 'Student 571 viewed Carbohydrates Websites', new Date(2015,08,10,20,22,01), new Date(2015,08,10,20,23,58)],
    ['Student 571', 'Learning Path', 'Student 571 viewed Lipids Textbooks', new Date(2015,08,10,20,23,58), new Date(2015,08,10,20,24,35)],
    ['Student 571', 'Supplemental Info', 'Student 571 viewed Nucleic Acids Websites', new Date(2015,08,10,20,24,35), new Date(2015,08,10,20,33,34)],
    ['Student 571', 'Supplemental Info', 'Student 571 watched Video: The Properties of Water', new Date(2015,08,10,20,33,34), new Date(2015,08,10,20,33,53)],
    ['Student 571', 'Supplemental Info', 'Student 571 viewed Lipids Websites', new Date(2015,08,10,20,33,53), new Date(2015,08,10,20,43,43)],
    ['Student 571', 'Supplemental Info', 'Student 571 viewed Complex Carbohydrates Are Formed by Linkage of Monosaccharides - Biochemistry - NCBI Bookshelf', new Date(2015,08, 10,20,43,43), new Date(2015,08, 10,20,53,28)],
    ['Student 571', 'Test Me', 'Student 571 scored 81% on Biological Chemistry Learning Path assessment', new Date(2015,08,10,20,53,28), new Date(2015,08,10,20,54,36)]
  ]);

  dashboard.bind(control, chart);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```css
div.google-visualization-tooltip {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="chart" style="position: relative; width: 985px; height: 100px;"></div>
  <div>Select a time range to zoom in.</div>
  <div id="control"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.. Yes, I also find similar thing here http://jsfiddle.net/nH2XL/

But how can we have x-axis as a straight line over which we can zoom-in/out as per need ?

Comment: don't follow the question -- i've found working with google charts, _some manipulation is required_ -- there aren't any standard zoom options, so it requires custom implementation